# How can i implement search box in hugo dot theme?

Tags: search, hugo

I have to create a hugo site for documentation. i am using [dot-hugo-documentation-theme](https://themes.gohugo.io/dot-hugo-documentation-theme/). How can i implement a search box in this theme?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 text-center mx-auto">
    <h1 class="text-white mb-3">{{ .Site.Params.banner.title }}</h1>
    <p class="text-white mb-4">{{ .Site.Params.banner.description }}</p>
        <div class="position-relative">
        <input id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ .Site.Params.banner.placeholder }}">
        <!-- Javascript -->
        <script>
            $(function() {
            var projects = [
                {{ range.Data.Pages }}
                {
                    // value: "{{ .Title }}",
                    label: "{{ .Title }}",

                    url:"{{ .Permalink }}"
                },
                {{ end }}
            ];
            $( "#search" ).autocomplete({
                minLength: 0,
                source: projects,
                focus: function( event, ui ) {
                    $( "#search" ).val( ui.item.label );
                    return false;
                },
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                    $( "#search" ).val( ui.item.label );
                    $( "#project-id" ).val( ui.item.value );
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
                return $( "<li>" )
                .append( "<a href=" + item.url + " + \" &quot;\" +  >" + item.label + "</a>" )
                .appendTo( ul );
            };
            });
        </script>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
{{ "<!-- /banner -->" | safeHTML }}
```

Using this display only main headings I have to display inner page headings?

Answer (score -1):

[This guide](https://gist.github.com/sebz/efddfc8fdcb6b480f567) will take you through the steps to enable Lunr-powered search on your Hugo site. It includes a Grunt script to do the indexing for you, so it's pretty straightforward.

If you want your search to work differently (e.g., through Elasticsearch), the [Hugo documentation on search](https://gohugo.io/tools/search/) explains other options.